# Violating the rules for filing a patent application

Tags: penalties

I have documentation that shows that a number of individuals who claimed to be the original inventors when they signed the Declaration (37 CFR 1.63) knowingly made false statements in the filing of a Patent Application. The USPTO claims that any cure would have to be handled by an Attorney. What good does the Declaration do if the office won't enforce their own rules?

Comment: I assume you made the USPTO aware of this documentation. What are you hoping the USPTO would have done?

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the pitfalls of Patent Law in particular, IP law overall, and the field of law in general.

It's quite common to see the opposite, where well funded individuals or companies can launch spurious challenges and suits, just to slow down their competitors.

There a version of the golden rule for business "He who has the gold, makes the rules" and that definitely comes into play in situations like these.

Because patent litigation, in particular, is extremely expensive, one strategy you might try is to reach out to competitors of the malefactors, and see if they'd be willing to fund a challenge.

If it's an invention with heavy social benefit, it might be possible to find an attorney willing to go [pro bono](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pro_bono).

Sorry I don't have better advice.  "The law is imperfect" is a fundamental concept, and here, you're dealing a regulatory agency, and potentially the courts, as opposed to elected officials and legislators.

Comment: Since this agency (USPTO) is a federal agency, wouldn't any violation also fall under the US Code 18 U.S.C. 1001?

Comment: It would, but the issue here is how the agency itself operates, i.e. procedure.  Many fields of law are somewhat arcane in this regard (communications law, for instance) but none is more arcane than patent law (thus a stack all it's own.)  That's likely why they're indicating an attorney is needed.